# How do I upload file to google drive using drive API using python?

Tags: python, api, google-drive-api

I want to upload a file to google drive using its API, I am using the code

```
def newer():
    url= 'https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media'
    data='''{{
      "name":"testing.txt",
    }}'''
    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
    print response.text
```

However, I am getting response error message as below.

> {  "error": {   "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "authError",
>       "message": "HTTP Basic Authentication is not supported for this API",
>       "locationType": "header",
>       "location": "Authorization"    }   ],   "code": 401,   "message": "HTTP Basic Authentication is not supported for this API"  } }

Is there some other way to do my job using python.

Should I need to sign in to google cloud to access API for authentication token or credentials

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally I Understood how do I upload file to google drive using api.

first you need to install python library which gives the methods to use drive api.
installing the library: pip install google-api-python-client
then code as below.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload,MediaIoBaseDownload
import io

# Setup the Drive v3 API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

above code snippet is to create object/variable which allow you to get inside the drive with a right credential. here `drive_service`  does that work.

File uploading code is below here.

```
def uploadFile():
    file_metadata = {
    'name': 'fileName_to_be_in_drive.txt',
    'mimeType': '*/*'
    }
    media = MediaFileUpload('Filename_of_your_local_file.txt',
                            mimetype='*/*',
                            resumable=True)
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    print ('File ID: ' + file.get('id'))
```

The file ID is important because if you want to download the file from the drive you need the file ID.

Comment: `from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload`

Comment: add `'parents':['folderID']` to the "file_metadata" above to put the file in a specific folder.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access private user data you need the permission of the user.  You cant upload to my drive account without my permission.

> USERNAME:PASSWORD

Is called [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and uses login and password google shut down for this in 2015.

In order to access private user data now you will need to use Oauth2.

I suggest starting with the [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

```
"""
Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.

Creates a Drive v3 API service and prints the names and ids of the last 10 files
the user has access to.
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Drive v3 API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Drive v3 API
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, Should I need to Login to the free trial of Google cloud platform for Oauth2?

Comment: What should be the content of credential.json and client_secret.json in above code DalmTo

Comment: The tutorial shows you how to create the json. file.  To be clear your question states you are uploading to Google Drive which has nothing to do with Google cloud platform.  You will be uploading files to the google drive account of the user who authenticates your code.

Comment: I understood for client_secret.json but did not get any idea about Credential.json

Comment: Credential.json is the file where user credentials should be saved to.   Follow the tutorial if it doesnt tell you to do something you dont need to do it.

Answer (score -4):

#### Simple Way

First, install the google drive library using:

```
!pip install gdown
```

#### Load data

Copy your google drive (ensure you have the correct google link):

```
!gdown https://test_google_url.com
```

If required, unzip the file:

```
!unzip test_file_here.zip
```

Comment: the question is about upload not download